# Can't create server-client system with using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, amazon-lightsail

I am making simple server-client system with using node.js and socket.io.
The server code runs on AWS Lightsail instance.
And the client code runs on my PC.

server.js is here.

```
    'use strict';
    
    const io = require('socket.io')();
    io.on('connection', client => {
        client.on('notice', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    
    io.listen(3000);
```

And client.js is here.

```
    'use strict';
    
    const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://***.***.***.***:3000');
    
    socket.emit('notice', {data: 1});
```

The port of the AWS instance is opened(tcp, 3000). But above codes doesn't work.

If above both codes run on my pc, these works properly(Sending address in the client.js is 'http://localhost:3000').

I'd like to tell me how to get the program to work properly.

My environment is here.
node.js: v15.0.1
socket.io: v3.0.1
socket.io-client: v3.0.1
my pc: macOS mojave v10.14.6
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2
AWS Lightsail instance: ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: What error does the browser produce when trying to connect?

Comment: I don't use any browser. The system is node.js - node.js communication system.
And there is no error messages. It just keeps silent...